# How is Wilkinson power divider lossy?

Tags: s-parameters, power-divider, scattering

In an ideal Wilkinson power divider(because in practical there will always be resistive loss), the scattering parameters, or S matrix is given as:

[image: S matrix]

From the condition that checks if network is loss-less or not which is:

*Say s-parameters matrix is S(nxn). Transpose of S is X and conjugate of S is Y then X.Y=I (Identity Matrix) if network is lossless.*

It turns out that **the power divider is lossy** as X.Y is not equal to I. Then how does the input power split equally at outputs? It means Pi=Po1+Po2(where Pi is input power, Po1 and Po2 are output powers at any 2 output ports; Po=Po1+Po2). Thus, net power loss=(Po-Pi)=0.

Does it not violate the fact that network is lossy. Or is it that Scattering parameters deal with the overall network meaning a lossy network can have a lossless path in it? If the latter is true then it makes sense to me and I can safely conclude that "A lossless network means all paths are lossless and a lossy means at least one path is lossy"[Path here meaning a road from any input to any output].

As stated in [Wilkinson Power Divider](https://www.everythingrf.com/community/what-is-a-wilkinson-power-divider), an image of which I am attaching if link goes down:
[image: Wilkinson Power Divider]
In its ideal form there would not be any resistive loss, so then would the s-parameter matrix differ from the one that I have attached above to reflect the lossless attribute?

Comment: Are you talking about an ideal divider, or a real one? What is the precise "condition that checks if a network is loss-less or not" that you're referring to?

Answer (score 3):

The ideal Wilkinson does not have any loss when transferring signals from port 1 to ports 2 and 3:
$$|S_{11}|^2 + |S_{21}|^2 + |S_{31}|^2 = 1$$

When the input is given at port 2 or port 3, it is not lossless:
$$|S_{12}|^2 + |S_{22}|^2 + |S_{32}|^2 \ne 1$$

Therefore we don't classify it as a lossless network in the general sense, even though it is lossless in its usual application.

Comment: So, that means a network that is categorized as lossy due to its S matrix can have at least one loss-less path, right?

Comment: @PrasanjitRath, no it means the author who said the Wilkinson divider is lossless was being sloppy about their terminology; or at least they were talking about its behavior in a specific application, not its theoretical properties.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no voltage across the resistor, there is no power loss.

This means that when the 'wilky' is used as a power divider into two equal impedances, it's lossless.

When it's used as a power combiner between two general signals, then their difference appears across the resistor, and it's lossy.

When it's used as a power combiner between two equal amplitude identical signals in phase, the resistor doesn't see a voltage, and it's lossless again.